# Javascript function sending html object

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I'm using Jquery Datatables.

I have the following code as one of my rows in aaData

```
case "opties" : $row[] = ("<button onclick='btnselecteer()' 
style='margin-left:5px;' class='btn grey btn-xs tooltips btn-selecteer' data-original-title='Selecteer/Deselecteer' data-placement='top' data-container='body'>
        <i class='fa fa-check'></i></button>");
break;
```

Which gives me a button in one of my table rows
Now I can't use

$(".btn-selecteer").on('click... so I'm using it with a function. I just can't figure out how to send the button somehow so I can make adjustments to it ( adding/removing a class)

Answer (score 0):

Just send over `this` and then you access it:

```
<button onclick='btnselecteer(this)'
```

Then for your js:

```
btnselecteer(btn) {
  $(btn).addClass('clicked');
}
```